# Time out expired issue while using save changes in breeze js

Tags: angularjs, breeze, azure-sql-database, asp.net-web-api

In my project i am using angular js with breeze js and i am using sql azure database 2012 it contains 50 gb records, while calling the save changes time out expired issue will come.why this issue will come if any body knows reply me.

Version of breeze is 1.4.7

Comment: How big is your transaction, i.e. how many records you are updating and what is the command timeout set to? If you are updating many records at once and command timeout is short you may hit this. Try increasing the command timeout and keep your transaction shorter. If you are hitting the resource limits try scaling up the database and execute the query, later you can scale down.

Comment: Ok thanks friend....

Comment: I will it check it out and tell...

Comment: Hi friend, but at the time I inserted only one record into two tables(Customer and AccountCustomer). In the customer table I used one trigger after insert. why this problem is coming friend....

Comment: What is the service objective of the database? Could you query sys.resource_stats on the master database for this user database and see the resource consumption during the query execution time? Also can you try executing the same query from SSMS and capture the duration